# paste command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, paste

I'm trying to merge columns from two different files within the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#

echo "1 1 1" > tmp1
echo "2 2 2" >> tmp1
echo "3 3 3" >> tmp1

echo "a,b,c" > tmp2
echo "a,b,c" >> tmp2
echo "a,b,c" >> tmp2

paste -d':' <(cut -d" " -f1 tmp1) <(cut -d"," -f 1-2 tmp2)
```

The above script works fine when I run

```
bash test.sh
```

However, it does not work when I run

```
sh test.sh
```

and I get the following error message

```
test.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 13: `paste -d':' <(cut -d" " -f1 tmp1) <(cut -d"," -f 1-2 tmp2)'
```

Could somebody explain what is the reason of this behaviour? Is there fix it? Thx.

Comment: [`sh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) and [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) are separate programs (though on some systems `sh` is pointed to `bash` for compatibility reasons). There's effectively no reason to ever use `sh`.

Comment: @dimo414 Unless, of course, you are trying to write a script that will work on any POSIX-compliant system, whether or not it has `bash` installed.

Comment: @chepner thus the "effectively" :) But if you're intent is to write a Bash script and aren't trying to support every backwater POSIX-only environment one could concoct, being `sh`-compliant is an unnecessary hassle.

Comment: There is a vast difference between "don't need `sh` compatibility" and "no reason to ever use `sh`", a difference not conveyed by the word "effectively".

Answer (score 1):

On your system, `sh` is presumably not set as `bash` (`dash` may be?).

The process substitution, `<()`, is `bash`-ism (comes from `ksh` actually), which is not defined by POSIX hence not portable.

So the shell you are using (`sh`) does not have the `<()` implementation, hence the syntax error on `(` (as `<` indicates input redirection so the error actually being shown for the first `(`).

Answer (score 1):

`<()` provide a syntactic alternative to manually managing named pipes.

```
trap 'rm p1 p2' EXIT
mkfifo p1 p2
cut -d " " -f1 tmp1 > p1 &
cut -d " " -f 1-2 tmp2 > p2 &

paste -d':' p1 p2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this portably using file descriptors

```
while
    IFS=" " read -r x rest <&3
    IFS="," read -r y z rest <&4
do
    echo "$x:$y:$z"
done 3<tmp1 4<tmp2
```

```
1:a:b
2:a:b
3:a:b
```

Tested with dash